# Spring cloud stream application configurable topic name

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to find a way to configure the topic that a spring cloud stream @StreamListener will listen to. My first attempt was to try to use SPeL to get this, eg.

```
@StreamListener("#{ systemProperties['topic.name'] }")
```

but the expression is not replaced and I end up with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic name can only have ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'
```

Is there any way to control what the topic name is when launching the application, rather than just at compile time with a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BeanPostProcessor` that handles `@StreamListener` does not support SpEL or property placeholders; it can only contain a bean name for the object (message channel) that is bound to the binder destination.

Exactly what are you trying to achieve? There is already an indirection between the destination and the channel via application.properties/yml.

Comment: I want to be able to choose which of a number of topics an instance of my application listens to when I run it.

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=foo,bar` and then `@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)` will listen on topics foo and bar.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the docs. That does solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if the destination contains any space between values - for example `destination=foo, bar`, then it causes the error:

`Topic name can only have ASCII alphanumerics.`

After I removed spaces, it worked for me. Just wanted to share it.